# ComponentOne Studio for ASP.NET AJAX installation issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, componentone

Hi anyone can help me with this issue...

I'm trying to install the ComponentOne Studio for asp.net ajax but halfway through it pop out this error:

```
GAC Operation Error

Unable to add c:\promgram files (x86)\componentone\studio for
asp.net\bin\v4\designer\C1.Web.UI.Design.4.dll to the Global Assembly Cache
```

Please advice me.. Thank you~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is observed due to lack of permissions to write in GAC. I would suggest you to run the setup with administrative privileges (right click and select 'Run as Administrator').

Thanks,
Richa